# Having Trouble with Semicolons in Formula for VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm having trouble with inserting this formula in my excel VBA Code. I understand that when including an apostrophe, it treats it as a note/comment and would be excluded from the code.

How would I go about fixing this? What would I replace the apostrophe with? Double quotes? Seems when it hits the indirect formula is when there is the issue.

```
Selection.formulaArray = "=INDEX('Insert Data 1'!$A$1:INDIRECT("'Insert Data 1'!B"&COUNTA('Insert Data 1'!A:A)),SMALL(IF('Insert Data 1'!$A$1:INDIRECT("'Insert Data 1'!A"&COUNTA('Insert Data 1'!A:A))=Table!$A1,ROW('Insert Data 1'!$A$1:INDIRECT("'Insert Data 1'!A"&COUNTA('Insert Data 1'!A:A)))-(COUNTIF(A1:INDIRECT("A"&COUNTA(A:A)),A1))),ROWS('Insert Data 1'!$A$1:INDIRECT("'Insert Data 1'!A"&COUNTA('Insert Data 1'!A:A)))),2)"
```

Thank You!

Comment: VBA code is OK with quoted apostrophes or single quotes; but any double quotes within a quoted string must be escaped (doubled).

Comment: Curious, did you use the macro recorder to create the Formula?

Comment: And also, what does your question have to do with `Semicolon`?

Comment: Break the formula into pieces instead of trying to do it all in one line. The way you are trying to do it makes it incredibly difficult to debug.

Comment: Not to mention it's going to prompt the user like that every time the sheet is calculated, and surely you dont want that.